# Can I add issues to github from the command line?

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, github-issues

I'm new to git and I'd like to be able to map plans and progress for my project through github.

The problem is, that requires lots of clicking around with a browser on github.com, and I'd like to be able to automate the task somewhat by using a command line program.

Is there a command line interface for github?

Comment: The options have changed since the last answer. See current options here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48913239/4752883

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could check out [this cli](http://rubygems.org/gems/ghi) for the Github issues API. 
Note this is specific to Github Issues only.

Hope this helps.

[edit] The original answer mentioned [this](https://github.com/jsmits/github-cli) application which doesn't function anymore and recommends `ghi`.

Comment: Note that `ghi` is [using a deprecated Github API](https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi/issues/387) and will likely stop working November 2020. The current (May 2020) recommendation should be https://cli.github.com/, as per @Xavier's answer.

Answer (score 22):

There's a [`ghi` gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/ghi) that you can use to manage issues.

> ```
> The most commonly used ghi commands are:
>    list        List your issues (or a repository's)
>    show        Show an issue's details
>    open        Open (or reopen) an issue
>    close       Close an issue
>    edit        Modify an existing issue
>    comment     Leave a comment on an issue
>    label       Create, list, modify, or delete labels
>    assign      Assign an issue to yourself (or someone else)
>    milestone   Manage project milestones
> ```

Answer (score 14):

With Github's new official [CLI](https://cli.github.com/) (command line interface):

```
gh issue create --title "How to create an issue?" --body "I need a github CLI"
```

See additional [details and options](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_issue_create) and [installation instructions](https://cli.github.com/manual/installation).

Answer (score 1):

There is a [github_cli](https://github.com/peter-murach/github_cli) gem that I'm working on that provides command line access to the entire GitHub API v3. Please give it a try and report any issue/thoughts/feature requests.

Answer (score 1):

[NodeGH](http://nodegh.io/) - Github command line tools. Let's you create new issue, comment, open or close.
You can find all the commands available at their [Github repo](https://github.com/node-gh/gh).

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options:

1. **Use the official command line interface supported by github:**

   Tutorial: http://pythonhosted.org/hub/

   Github repo: https://github.com/github/hub (~12k stars)
2. **Use the NodeH interface**:

   Tutorial: http://nodegh.io/

   Github repo: https://github.com/node-gh/gh
3. **Use the ghi interface:**

   Tutorial and Github repo: https://github.com/stephencelis/ghi/

All 3 look cool. The `hub` app looks like it has the most stars and is officially supported by github. So its most likely to be maintained for the long term. 
So, if I were looking for a solution that would be supported for a long term, I would go with option#1: `hub`