# Pushing issues and wiki to Github repo

Tags: git, github, gitlab, backup, devops

I want to move my GitHub repo from GitHub to GitLab. I want to move everything(issues, wiki and ...).
I use [python-github-backup](https://github.com/josegonzalez/python-github-backup) and backup everything but I do not know how to push issues and wiki.
I search and find out I can use `git push URL/repo.wiki.git` but it does not work in my scenario.

How can I push issues and wiki?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Move a repository from Github to Gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54972004/11725753)? If so, please confirm it with the button above.

Comment: If you're getting an error when making initial push to a wiki repo, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41423798/11725753).

Answer (score 1):

You must use `git clone`, not `git push`.

To edit Wikis locally, you must first clone the Wiki.
Say, the GitHub username is `test`, and the repository name is `test-repo`.

In order to do so, you must run the following command in Git bash:

```
git clone https://github.com/test/test-repo.wiki.git
```

About the issues, this may help you do
various operations with [issues locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002908/can-i-add-issues-to-github-from-the-command-line).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have md file and want to push them and as I said in question 
git push https://github.com/test/test-repo.wiki.git  does not work  and it does not push it to wiki

Comment: If I clone and then change and then push it works but when I use python-github-backup it does not create .git  and when I create it with git init and ...   and after that push it does not work

Comment: Maybe if you update the Wiki via the GitHub UI could work.